# Validate Ember objects before route transition

Tags: validation, ember.js

I have an ember application with several objects on a settings page. These have a set of validations which I call as various points.

I also have an ember `{{link-to}}` helper which allows a user to transition to a results page.

I'd like to ensure my objects are valid before I allow the user to transition to the results page.

In Ember 2.0+ I was able to bind a function to a button rather than using the `{{link-to}}` helper and in the function could validate and call `transitionToRoute`.

I've had to downgrade the ember version to 1.1 and reverted to using the `{{link-to}}` helper due to some third party styling concerns. What is the best way to do this? in older Ember?

Is there a way to call a function before transition in the {{link-to}} helper? I couldn't seem to find one.

Comment: Did you try to use the route's beforeModel() hook ? I think it would be better choice for model validation in ember 2.x too.

Comment: @lependu that makes sense, would the psuedo logic be : Check model & controller validation state, if pass > do nothing else transitionToRoute(whereWeCameFrom)

Comment: Exactly. Here is an example for 2.x: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_beforeModel

Comment: This would work, but I think the willTransition action in the route seems like an earlier place to stop the code, rather than transitioning and moving back.

Comment: Yeah, I think it makes more sense. It is time to refactor :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend willTransition.

```
App.FormRoute = Ember.Route.extend({


actions: {
    willTransition: function(transition) {
      if (this.controller.get('userHasEnteredData') &&
          !confirm("Are you sure you want to abandon progress?")) {
        transition.abort();
      } else {
        // Bubble the `willTransition` action so that
        // parent routes can decide whether or not to abort.
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/routing/preventing-and-retrying-transitions/

Comment: This seems to fit the bill, not sure how I missed this first time round :s